# Biztalk security groups

Tags: active-directory, biztalk

As a prerequisite for BizTalk installation, there are security groups that need to be created and users put in those groups in active directory.

```
BizTalk Application Users
BizTalk Isolated Host Users
BizTalk Server Administrators
BizTalk Server B2B Operators .....
```

Some suggestions pointed out that those security groups need to be Global but my organization only allows us to create these groups within our OU.

So my question is if those groups are created within our OU only vs created as global group, will it have any negative implication/restriction to future BizTalk operations?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a problem here.  BizTalk Groups should be Global type, as opposed to Universal or Local.  But, you can create Global Groups in an Organization Unit defined in AD.

Meaning, Global is a *type* of Group, not the *scope* of the Group.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I would like to reconfirm to make sure I understand your explanation correctly. You said if I have an OU called ABC and have BizTalk groups under ABC is fine. The effect is still the same as having the groups outside ABC?

Comment: @user1205746 Yes.  I've never had cause to think otherwise and I've seen the BizTalk Groups defined on different locations.  Keep in mind, this is very easy to test.  Have them create Global Groups in in the BizTalk OU then try it out.  Modifying AD Groups and/or re-configuring BizTalk is pretty easy.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!